# Replace all the string occurance containing escape character in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have string that is dynamic and need to change along with escape character.
Suppose

```
var key = "Any String";
var term = "^"+key+"^";
var description = description.replace(term,"replacement_string");
```

it replace only first occurrence and works well.it changes
like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ^Any String^ and Any String Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ^Any String^

to

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet replacement_string and Any String Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ^Any String^

if I use replace globally then it doesn't work

```
var key = "Any String";
var term = "/\^"+key+"\^/g";
var description = description.replace(term,"replacement_string");
```

print like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ^Any String^ and Any String Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ^Any String^

I need to change all occurance of ^Any String^ not if `Any String` doesn't have `^` then it shouldn't change the word.
Result should be like this.

> This is a description with replacement_string and Any String also need to change replacement_string

Comment: `"/\^"+key+"\^/g";` is just a string and not a regular expression.

Comment: term = new RegExp("^"+key+"^", "g");

Comment: Sorry but doesn't work

Comment: `^` is a metacharacter in regex. You need to escape it. `var term = new RegExp('\\^' + key + '\\^', 'g')`

Comment: Thanks you save my day